# VScode: Kotlin plugin autocomplete not working

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, code-completion

Today I first started programming with Kotlin in VScode. I installed the [Kotlin plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin) (which as I understood this plugin should provide autocomplete feature), but strangely when I start writing code, the autocompletion doesn't work.

This is in continuation of another problem I faced today with the above plugin that presented an error described [here](https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/issues/48), that after taking the steps suggested [here](https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/issues/48#issuecomment-653801002) the error disappeared and it seems to be resolved.
But still when I write code I don't get autocompletion.

I also saw on the [plugin page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin#debugging) (in the Debugging §Setup section) the following instruction:

> Open the launch.json file in your project and invoke code completion to create a new launch configuration (or select Add Configuration... in the debug tab)

I don't know if this is what should solve my problem, anyway, this is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch kotlin script",
            "type": "kotlin",
            "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "mainClass": "${workspaceFolder}/MainKt.main",
            "request": "launch",
        }
    ]
}
```

If there is a special configuration that needs to be set in launch.json, then I don't know what exactly needs to be there for it to work.